Why can Euler's identity be used to express a sinusoid with a single exponential?
I'm unsure how 4.1.5 is used to express the value in 4.1.4... any advice or tips?


This seems like a sub-optimal text to me. As Dilip pointed out they use the same symbol $x_a(t)$ for two different things, which is just plain sloppy. The statement of "frequency is inherently positive" also seems quite wrong to me.

I agree with Hilmar, this is not a very good description of exponential signals or frequency. The statement "However, in many cases, only for mathematical convenience, we need to introduce negative frequencies." is not very helpful as frequencies described using $cos(\theta)$ are also "only for mathematical convenience". It is all math and is used to describe our physical world, whether we use "real" signals or "complex" signals, it's all mathematical convenience. Where did this text come from?

I got this from Digital Signal Processing: Principles, Algorithms and Applications, 5e, from Pearson.
The 4.1.1 signal in the text is:
x_a(t) = Acos(Ωt + θ), where -inf < t < inf

The way the textbook is written it looks like they are meant to be the same thing

They are NOT the same thing. (4.1.4) is complex and (4.1.6) is real. To precise (4.1.6) is the real part of (4.1.4). These are only the same if both $\Omega = 0$ and $\phi = n\cdot\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which means $x_a(t)$ would have to be a real constant.

The well-known twentieth-century American columnist Dorothy Parker once reviewed a book saying
"This is not a book to be put down lightly; it should be thrown with great force."
Perhaps this sage advice should be applied to the book the OP is reading!

I concur with the others. The RHS's of 4.1.4 and 4.1.6 are clearly not equal. Giving the benefit of the doubt though, 4.1.4 could just be a typo. I don't have the book though so I can't answer that.

"I got this from Digital Signal Processing: Principles, Algorithms and Applications, 5e, from Pearson" Are the authors Proakis and Manolakis? If so, the level of sloppiness is surprising.  Proakis's (earlier) books (I have read only the digital communications ones) have a much better (and well-deserved) reputation.

Yes, This is from Proakis and Manolakis.


"Any advice?"

Yes, read the text very carefully. The  $x_a(t)$ in $(4.1.4)$ is not the same as the $x_a(t)$ in  $(4.1.6)$. The $x_a(t)$ in $(4.1.6)$ is the one defined in $(4.1.1)$ as a sinusoidal signal, and you should use $(4.1.5)$ in its full glory as
\begin{align}
e^{j\phi} &= \cos(\phi) + j\sin(\phi) \tag{4.1.5a}\\
e^{-j\phi} &= \cos(\phi) - j\sin(\phi) \tag{4.1.5b}
\end{align}
to deduce that
\begin{align}
\cos(\phi) &= \dfrac{e^{j\phi} + e^{-j\phi}}{2} \tag{4.1.5c}\\
\sin(\phi) &= \dfrac{e^{j\phi} - e^{-j\phi}}{2j} \tag{4.1.5d}
\end{align}
and then replace $\phi$ by $\Omega t+\theta$ in $(4.1.5c)$.
If you are planning on doing any more reading on this kind of stuff, I recommend having $(4.1.5a)$-$(4.1.5d)$ engraved on your heart in letters of gold to save a lot of puzzling over the same stuff over and over again.

These are all variations of Euler's Formula, and I have accepted those as true. My problem is that even if the two x_a(t)'s from 4.1.4 and 4.1.6 are not the same, I still don't get how the sinusoid in 4.1.1 was able to be defined with a single exponent in 4.1.4. I

Looking through the textbook as carefully as possible, it seems like the two x_a(t)'s are the same

Throw away your book and get a different one, hopefully not by the same author.
